# Settings GCC (ARM-Linux) in Eclipse Mars for 'C project

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I am experimenting with cross compiling for ARM-Linux under Windows using Eclipse-Mars. My set-up is as follows:

- Win10 x64
- Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- GNU Toolchain for RaspberryPi (SysGCC)
- Target platform: RaspberryPi2 running Raspian
- Source project in 'C (not C++) using Linux Threads (pthreads)

I have knocked up a small 'C project using 'pthreads' which compiles under Eclipse and runs successfully on the Pi.

My problem is that Eclipse shows a number of errors in its **Problems TAB** to do with Linux's threads:

- Type 'pthread_cond_t' could not be resolved
- Type 'pthread_mutex_t' could not be resolved
- Type 'pthread_t' could not be resolved

I have Eclipse as:

- **Cross GCC Compiler** settings to use **g++** with **-std=c++11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0**.
- **Cross G++ Compiler** settings to use **g++** with **-std=c++11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0**.

In other words both are the same.

If I rename my source files from **foo.c** to **foo.cpp** and recompile, then the Eclipse errors disappear!!!

This implies that Eclipse's C++ settings are correct, but its 'C settings are not.

Can anybody suggest anything for me to try?

Answer (score 0):

g++ ist a C++ compiler, so you might try to use other settings for the Cross GCC Compiler, eg. gcc.

Also make sure you are linking the pthread library.

Comment: Yes I am aware that **g++** is a C++ compiler, but my understanding is that it can also be used to compile 'C code. I have already ensured that the **pthread** library is linked in - the code runs correctly on the target platform. Could my issue be something to do with Eclipse's **live code analysis** settings?